# Avoid Absolute Position in Css in Material-UI and React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How do I avoid using `position: absolute` for the "Hello There" button?
The layout should stay the same. I just want to get rid of that css property.
Is better approach? Pls fork my codesandbox below:

CODESANDBOX -----> [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-wright-w4hs8u?file=/demo.js)

```
<MainContainer>
  <Stack spacing={1}>
    {products?.map((product) => (
      <ProductItem
        key={product.id}
        name={product.name}
        description={product.description}
      />
    ))}
  </Stack>
  <Stack
    alignItems={"center"}
    sx={{
      marginTop: 2,
      position: "absolute",
      display: "flex",
      left: 0,
      right: 0
    }}
  >
    <Button variant="outlined" sx={{ bgcolor: "white" }}>
      Hello There
    </Button>
  </Stack>
</MainContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with `position: relative` and `top,` but not sure if that's what you're going for.

```
  <Stack alignItems={"center"}>
    <Button variant="outlined" sx={{ bgcolor: "white", position: 'relative', top: 50 }}>
      Hello There
    </Button>
  </Stack>
```

Could you please elaborate on what result you want to accomplish?

I would recommend using `position: absolute` as you were. It's a perfect usage of it currently when you want to layer something on top without expanding the underlying box model.

Comment: Same layout as my codesandbox. Just wanted to avoid using `position: absolute`. I wanted to use best coding standards. Can you fork my codesandbox?

Comment: Sure, here's my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/late-haze-9mksij?file=/demo.js

Comment: There's nothing wrong in using `position: absolute` as long as you don't style your entire app with it.

Comment: Your fork is adding some margin on top of the buttons?

Comment: No, I removed the styling on `Stack` and added `position: relative` and `top: 50` on the `Button`.

Comment: Pls check the screenshot of your work here https://imgur.com/a/cdNHxfb. and compare it to my codesandbox

Comment: I would recommend using `position: absolute` as you were. It's a perfect usage of it currently when you want to layer something on top without expanding the underlying box model.

Comment: The problem with position absolute is that I'm setting a dynamic height which isnt here in codesandbox. So it kinda affects it

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by dynamic height?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a non answer but, you probably shouldn't. Making a fully relative layout in this situation would requiere a layout that is a lot more complicate, where your dotter border would exist in a "layer" behind. And even then, to make that "layer" you would use a div that HAS absolute position.

Your use of position absolute here seems very correct, it is responsive, self contained, and used exactly for the type of things position absolute is ACTUALLY designed to solve.

Do you have a particular reason to want to remove the absolute position? If it's bringing any negative effects maybe they can be mitigated some other way.

Comment: The problem with position absolute is that I'm setting a dynamic height which isnt here in codesandbox. So it kinda affects it

Answer (score 0):

Replace that with `position: fixed`.
If have problems with fixed position too, you can use a `relative` position and tweak its `top` and `margin-top` styles.

```
<Stack alignItems={"center"}>
  <Button
    variant="outlined"
    sx={{
      bgcolor: "white",
      position: "relative",
      top: 96,
      marginTop: -10,
    }}
  >
    Hello There
  </Button>
</Stack>
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/no-absolute-position-1i45vp?file=/demo.js)